# Laravel how to join one to many relationship tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I want to display list of data by joining tables that have one to many relationship.

Currently, I do this by going through the loop and make queries to retrieve data. This way, I think, is very inefficient, because if I were to display 1000 rows of data record, I will have to go 1000 loops to append other data with one-to-many relationship.

I am thinking to get around this problem using cache but it does not seem to solve fundamental problem.

For more understanding I have shared tables that I want do join as below.

**Post Table**

```
| id | comment_id | status |
|----|------------|--------|
| 1  | 1          | 0      |
| 2  | 2          | 0      |
| 3  | 3          | 1      |
| 4  | 4          | 0      |
| 5  | 5          | 1      |
| 6  | 6          | 1      |
```

**Comment Table**

```
| id | order_id | content  |
|----|----------|----------|
| 1  | 1        | hi       |
| 2  | 1        | hellow   |
| 3  | 1        | yes      |
| 4  | 1        | okay     |
| 5  | 2        | bye      |
| 6  | 2        | good bye |
```

If I were to join Table `Post` with Table `Comment`, because they have one to many relationship, rows would not match. How would I join these two tables to show the list of post with comments?

**Sample List Controller**

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function list(Request $request)
{
    $vaildData = $request->validate([
        'comment_id' => 'numeric',
    ]);

    $posts = new PostModel;
    $posts->find(1);
    $displayPosts = [];

    foreach ( $posts->find(1)->get() as $post ) {
        $displayPosts->comments = $post->comment()->get();
    }

    return $displayPosts;
}
```

**Post Model**
    namespace App\Model\Post;

```
use SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Post\Comment’, ‘post_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: do u want to do this the laravel way or php way?

Comment: I want to know laravel way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [with()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for eager loading your comments.

```
$posts = PostModel::with('comments')->find($id);
```

So your function will be like-

```
public function list(Request $request)
{
   $vaildData = $request->validate([
    'comment_id' => 'numeric',
   ]);

   $posts = PostModel::with('comments')->find(1);
   return $displayPosts;
}
```

You can filter your comments with comment_id using [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) like the following-

```
$comment_id = $request->input('comment_id');
$posts = PostModel::with('comments')->whereHas('comments', function ($query) use($comment_id)
      {
        $query->where('id', '=', $comment_id);
      })->find(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Firstly, you may refer to this documentation.

To setup one-to-many relationship for Post and Comment table:

1. A Post has Many Comments
2. So in you Comment table there should be a column named post_id
3. Inside your Post.php

```html
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment’);
}
```

4. Inside your controller

```html
public function list(Request $request){
    $posts = Post::where('id', 1)
                  ->with('comments')
                  ->get()

    return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`public function list(Request $request, $id)`

`{`

`$vaildData = $request->validate([`
        `'comment_id' => 'numeric',`
    ]);

```
$posts = PostModel::find($id);

return $posts->comments;
```

`}`

try this... Hope this can help you

or you can try like this

`public function list(Request $request, $id)`

`{`

`$vaildData = $request->validate([`
        `'comment_id' => 'numeric',`
    ]);

```
$posts = PostModel::find($id)->comments()->get();

return $posts;
```

`}`

Answer (score 2):

```
public function list(Request $request)
{
    $vaildData = $request->validate([
        'comment_id' => 'numeric',
    ]);

    $posts = new PostModel;
    $results = $posts->find(1)->with('comments')//comments is the function name you defined in the App\Model\Post
    return resurts;
}
```

collection results contain the infomation of the post and another extra comment collection that belong to the post